# $parent variable corrupted when set from separate controller on ng-include

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I am having a hard time understanding why the following code stops working altogether.  Basically when I try to hide and show an ng-include using ng-show from the $parent scope it works fine.  For instance in the attached plnkr if you hit "Create New" then "Cancel", or just "Toggle" the visibility of the ng-include is appropriately set.

However, if I try to set the visibility from the child scope Cancel, it works once, and then it fails completely.  When you hit the "Cancel" button that is in the ng-include, the variable "createItemVisible" from the parent scope that controls visibility is somehow corrupted.

I've read through many other posts on $parent scope but I never saw a mention of where it works once and then not again.

The plnkr is here http://plnkr.co/edit/1tNpTzEBnTRHgvx6o0dc?p=preview

Here is the index.html code:

```
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
<h3>Items</h3>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="createItem()">Create New Item</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-alert" ng-click="createItemVisible=!createItemVisible">Toggle</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" ng-click="createItemVisible=false">Cancel</button>

<div ng-include="'inlineform.html'" ng-show="createItemVisible"></div>

</div>
```

Here is the inlineform.html code:

```
<div ng-controller="ItemDetailCtrl">
  <button type="button" class="close" ng-click="cancelItemDetail()">&times;</button>
  <h3>New Item</h3>

  <button ng-click="cancelItemDetail()" class='btn btn-danger'>Cancel</button>
</div>
```

Here is the script:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {

  $scope.createItemVisible = false;

  $scope.createItem = function() {
    $scope.createItemVisible = true;
  };

});

myApp.controller('ItemDetailCtrl', function($scope) {

  $scope.cancelItemDetail = function() {
    $scope.$parent.createItemVisible = false;
  }

});
```

Comment: It happens because you use primitives on the scope, you should learn angular before trying to code.

Comment: I am trying to learn angular that is why I asked my question.  I am just a beginner which is why my question might seem naive to you. I found your comment helpful nonetheless.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

From a comment by Ilan Frumer I was able to better understand that you should not use primitives on the scope.  I created a namespace to hold my variable.

```
var main = {
  createItemVisible : false
};
```

Then I registered this namespace with the scope.

```
$scope.main = main;
```

I then updated any references accordingly.

Here is the updated plnkr http://plnkr.co/edit/1tNpTzEBnTRHgvx6o0dc?p=preview